# Create a multidimensional array

Tags: go

How can I create an array of arrays, in Go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on @Kevin Burke's answer, strictly speaking

```
a := [][]byte{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

Is a [slice](http://golang.org/doc/articles/slices_usage_and_internals.html) of slices.  Which is quite different internally to an [array](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) of arrays.

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/w8tsvtb5ZO)

```
fmt.Println("Array of Arrays")
a := [2][2]int{{0, 1}, {2, 3}}
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    for j := 0; j < 2; j++ {
        fmt.Printf("a[%d][%d] = %d at %p\n", i, j, a[i][j], &a[i][j])
    }
}

fmt.Println("Slice of Slices")
b := [][]int{{0, 1}, {2, 3}}
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    for j := 0; j < 2; j++ {
        fmt.Printf("b[%d][%d] = %d at %p\n", i, j, b[i][j], &b[i][j])
    }
}
```

Internally an array of arrays is just a contiguous bit of memory so it is quite efficient, whereas a slice of slices is more complicated.  Each sub slice can be a different size and is allocated in a different place.  The slice headers take up extra RAM and use extra indirections to access.

For example [creating 100,000 3x3 array of arrays](http://play.golang.org/p/KJKjMvRQpz) uses up 5.03 MB of RAM whereas [creating 100,000 3x3 slices of slices](http://play.golang.org/p/3cxNtUB4Jv) uses up 13.79 MB of RAM.

A slice of slices is much more flexible - each row can have a different size, but if you just want a 2x2 matrix then an array of arrays is a much better choice.

Another difference is that slices are reference types - if you pass a slice to a function you'll be altering the original slice in the function.  Arrays are not - if you pass one to a function you'll be making a copy which can be slow, or could be what you want. If you want to modify it then pass a pointer.

[Here is an example](http://play.golang.org/p/J27K804CF8)

```
func f1(a [2][2]int) {
    fmt.Println("I'm a function modifying an array of arrays argument")
    a[0][0] = 100
}

func f2(b [][]int) {
    fmt.Println("I'm a function modifying an slice of slices argument")
    b[0][0] = 100
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Array of arrays")
    a := [2][2]int{{0, 1}, {2, 3}}
    fmt.Printf("Before %v\n", a)
    f1(a)
    fmt.Printf("After %v\n\n", a)

    fmt.Println("Slice of slices")
    b := [][]int{{0, 1}, {2, 3}}
    fmt.Printf("Before %v\n", b)
    f2(b)
    fmt.Printf("After %v\n", b)
}
```

Which prints

```
Array of arrays
Before [[0 1] [2 3]]
I'm a function modifying an array of arrays argument
After [[0 1] [2 3]]

Slice of slices
Before [[0 1] [2 3]]
I'm a function modifying an slice of slices argument
After [[100 1] [2 3]]
```

In general for one dimensional things a slice is pretty much always better than an array.  However for multidimensional of a fixed size then arrays of arrays are a better choice.

Answer (score 6):

Use nested braces:

```
a := [][]byte{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```